# Rails: Sqlite3 to PostgreSQL heroku deployment Undefined Table ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, database-schema

I've built a rails app and on pushing it up to heroku and running `heroku run rake db:migrate` i receive the error:

```
Migrating to CreateFollowingRelationships (20160615113231)
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
== 20160615113231 CreateFollowingRelationships: migrating =====================
-- create_table(:following_relationships)
   (7.1ms)  CREATE TABLE "following_relationships" ("id" serial primary key, "follower_id" integer, "followed_user_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_39102b381e"
FOREIGN KEY ("follower_id")
  REFERENCES "followers" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_048c8f7cd9"
FOREIGN KEY ("followed_user_id")
  REFERENCES "followed_users" ("id")
)
   (0.5ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.5ms)  SELECT pg_advisory_unlock(2837140123622957145)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "followers" does not exist
: CREATE TABLE "following_relationships" ("id" serial primary key, "follower_id" integer, "followed_user_id" integer, "created_at" timestamp NOT NULL, "updated_at" timestamp NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_39102b381e"
FOREIGN KEY ("follower_id")
  REFERENCES "followers" ("id")
, CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_048c8f7cd9"
FOREIGN KEY ("followed_user_id")
  REFERENCES "followed_users" ("id")
)
```

The relationship I have setup is for users to follow users and be followed. It works perfectly in development. This is the first time i've had this error and can't find a solution. Please see the rest of my code below.

### db/schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160618122126) do

  create_table "chats", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "profile_id"
    t.index ["profile_id"], name: "index_chats_on_profile_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_chats_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "profile_id"
    t.integer  "chat_id"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["chat_id"], name: "index_comments_on_chat_id"
    t.index ["profile_id"], name: "index_comments_on_profile_id"
  end

  create_table "following_relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "follower_id"
    t.integer  "followed_user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.index ["followed_user_id"], name: "index_following_relationships_on_followed_user_id"
    t.index ["follower_id"], name: "index_following_relationships_on_follower_id"
  end

  create_table "locations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "locationable_type"
    t.integer  "locationable_id"
    t.string   "suburb"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "country"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.index ["locationable_type", "locationable_id"], name: "index_locations_on_locationable_type_and_locationable_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_locations_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "buyer_id"
    t.integer  "seller_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "profile_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["profile_id"], name: "index_posts_on_profile_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_posts_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "bio"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_profiles_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "tutoring_relationships", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "tutor_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "tutee_id"
    t.index ["tutee_id"], name: "index_tutoring_relationships_on_tutee_id"
    t.index ["tutor_id"], name: "index_tutoring_relationships_on_tutor_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                           null: false
    t.string   "password_digest",                 null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                      null: false
    t.string   "username"
    t.boolean  "tutor",           default: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true
  end

  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "votable_type"
    t.integer  "votable_id"
    t.string   "voter_type"
    t.integer  "voter_id"
    t.boolean  "vote_flag"
    t.string   "vote_scope"
    t.integer  "vote_weight"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.index ["votable_id", "votable_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_votable_id_and_votable_type_and_vote_scope"
    t.index ["voter_id", "voter_type", "vote_scope"], name: "index_votes_on_voter_id_and_voter_type_and_vote_scope"
  end

end
```

### models/following_relationship.rb

```
class FollowingRelationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :follower, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :followed_user, class_name: 'User'
end
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :chats
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password_digest, presence: true

  has_many :follower_relationships,
    foreign_key: :followed_user_id,
    class_name: 'FollowingRelationship'
  has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships

  has_many :followed_user_relationships,
    foreign_key: :follower_id,
    class_name: "FollowingRelationship"
  has_many :followed_users, through: :followed_user_relationships



  has_many :tutee_relationships,
    foreign_key: :tutor_id,
    class_name: 'TutoringRelationship'
  has_many :tutees, through: :tutee_relationships

  has_many :tutor_relationships,
    foreign_key: :tutee_id,
    class_name: 'TutoringRelationship'
  has_many :tutors, through: :tutor_relationships

  def following? user
    followed_user_ids.include?(user.id)
  end

  def is_connected? user
    tutee_ids.include?(user.id)
  end
end
```

Please excuse the messy model, it would usually be in a helper method but for this post it's here. If anyone has any ideas please let me know! Thanks

Comment: Where in your db/schema.rb is the "followers" table that you're referencing?

Comment: @d1ll1nger the followers table exists only in User.rb. It's a sudo table that references ```class_name: 'FollowingRelationship'```. The relationships have been set this way so that the current_user doesn't go into both the followed_user AND the follower columns when clicking the follow button. It works perfectly, just Postgres is struggling with it. I originally found this technique through the thoughtbot guys and their 'upcase' tutorials, specifically the intermediate path.